# Fetching only related properties from related data in Entity Framework Core

Tags: linq, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

Using the `Include()` method from LINQ, I can easily fetch all attributes from the related `Users` table.

```
public IEnumerable<Group> GetAllUserGroups()
{
    IEnumerable<Group> groups = _dbContext.Group
                                          .Include(g => g.Users)
                                          .ToList<Group>();

    return groups;
}
```

But, I'm not sure how to select only the first name and the last name from the users table. I figured, it will be easiest to create a DTO, but then I am not really sure how to populate the DTO since Users is a list.

Essentially, `Group` and `User` have a one-to-many relationship.

`User` class:

```
public class User
{
    [Key]
    public int UserID { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }

    public int GroupID { get; set; }

    [JsonIgnore]
    public Group Group { get; set; }
}
```

`Group` class:

```
public class Group
{
    [Key]
    public int GroupID { get; set; }
    public string GroupName { get; set; }
    public List<User> Users { get; set; }
}
```

Thanks for suggestions.

Comment: *"how to **select** only the first name and the last name..."* - use `Select` instead of `Include`. And better create a special classes (aka DTO, ViewModel etc.) for query results which do not project (select) full entities. AutoMapper projections could help not writing manual code for selecting individual fields.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the following way, you can select the User with only `FirstName` and `LastName` contains value and other properties are null/empty/0:

```
IEnumerable<Group> groups = _dbContext.Group
                                .Select(a => new Group { 
                                    GroupID= a.GroupID,
                                    GroupName= a.GroupName,
                                    Users= a.Users.Select(b=>new User() { FirstName= b.FirstName,LastName= b.LastName}).ToList(),
                                }).ToList();
```

[image]

If you only want to display FirstName and LastName property value without other properties, you can use the anonymous class:

```
var groups = _dbContext.Group
                    .Select(a => new  { 
                        a.GroupID,a.GroupName,
                        Users= a.Users.Select(b=>new { b.FirstName,b.LastName}).ToList(),
                    }).ToList();
```

[image]

If you want to use the DTO, you need create the GroupDTO and UserDTO like below:

```
var groups = _dbContext.Group
                    .Select(a => new GroupDTO { 
                        GroupName= a.GroupName,
                        GroupID=  a.GroupID,    
                        Users=a.Users.Select(b=>new UserDTO() { FirstName=b.FirstName,LastName=b.LastName}).ToList()
                    }).ToList();
```

[image]